# Button type attribute has not been set.Microsoft Edge Toolsbutton-type

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I just installed the MS Tools for Vscode, and was just testing with buttons in html, here's my code:
HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fancy Button</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap">

</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <button id="button1">Hover me</button>
        <button id="button2">Hover me 2</button>
        <button id="button3">Hover me 3</button>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```css
* {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* Button 1 */

#button1 {
    background-color: black;
    border: 5px solid orange;
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    font-family: Poppins;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#button1:hover {
    transform: translateY(-7px);
    border-color: yellow;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5em 0.5em -0.4em yellow;
}

/* Button 2 */


#button2 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 157, 255);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    font-family: Poppins;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#button2:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

/* Button 3 */


#button3 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 208, 255);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    font-family: Poppins;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 5px solid rgb(0, 208, 255);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#button3:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 208, 255);
    background-color: black;

}
```

Somehow it got this warning that wasn't the case before I installed the extension:

```
Button type attribute has not been set.Microsoft Edge Toolsbutton-type
```

I tried googling and even looking for answers online and even StackoverFlow but no result came in. I would really appreciate it if you guys help me.

Answer (score 1):

**You must specify the type of button...**

***button-type*** checks if all buttons have a attribute set.***type***

**What does the hint check?**

This hint checks whether the attribute of a is explicitly set.**type**

**Examples that trigger the hint**

```
<button></button>
```

**Examples that pass the hint**

```
<button type="submit"></button>
<button type="button"></button>
```

Never forget type="button" on generated buttons!

**Read more about it**

- https://webhint.io/docs/user-guide/hints/hint-button-type/
- [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#type:~:text=popovertargetaction%22toggle%22-,type,-The%20default%20behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#type:%7E:text=popovertargetaction%22toggle%22-,type,-The%20default%20behavior)